# facebook like button ie7

Tags: facebook, button, internet-explorer-7, facebook-like

I have added a FB Like button through the standard method to a page. It works in all browsers except in IE7 where it gets shrunk down in width. Is there any fix for this. I have searched extensively, but all solutions don't work. You can see an example here:

http://www.swirl-test.net/test.html

You can view the source code of the page to see the implementation method.

Comment: IE7 users might not use facebook enough for even Facebook to care: http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2011/12/30/not-a-fan-of-timeline-on-facebook-use-ie7-facebook-stopped-supporting-it/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with fixing this on your end comes from the fact that the like button is a iframe pointed at Facebook's server, so you have no control over it's content and style (apart from the controls that Facebook exposes)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Was just hoping that maybe there was some work around that someone had discovered. I know that the cross domain issues disallows any alteration of the iframe content. I do see it working here, but I can't see how they got this to work: http://www.sunbrella.com/fabric/?style=6020-0000

Comment: This is the URL they are using to generate the button - http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=google.com&send=false&layout=button_count&width=100&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21 can you see if it works in your copy of IE7?  It works on my computer (with IETester, but its not a perfect way to test stuff like this)

Comment: It doesn't work in a real version of IE7 (note, if the button is in the liked state the button is fine, but if it is not liked yet, that is when the problem arises, in any implementation of this button on any site.)

Comment: Weird. Do you see my example in the original post here correctly or not?

Comment: http://imgur.com/Hxcr4wH - Also when I click on the like button I get a script error from Facebook.  I think it's heroic of you to want to support IE7, maybe it's time to let go :)

Comment: Yeah, then there's that! Thanks!